# How to generate diff between two folders on Windows using command line?

Tags: windows, cmd

We use Jenkins to deploy application files. I need copy files in a folder to a remote server via FTP using command line on Windows.

Normally only a few files in the folder are updated, and I don't want to transfer all files every time.

Is there a tool that can compare two folders and generate a new folder containing updated or new files?

Thanks.

Comment: Robocopy, beyond compare, ...

Comment: robocopy and xcopy both support the option `/M` to copy only files with archive attribute set in source directory and then remove the archive attribute after successful copying of source file to destination directory. Windows sets the archive attribute automatically when a file is created or modified in a directory. Run in a command prompt window `robocopy /?` and `xcopy /?` for help on those two commands.